# Check if dictionary is empty but with keys

Tags: python, dictionary, is-empty

I have a dictionary, which may only have these  keys. But there can be 2 keys, for example `'news'` and `'coupon'` or only `'coupon'`. How to check if the dictionary is empty? (The dictionaries below are empty.)

```
{'news': [], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
{'news': [], 'coupon': []}
```

I wrote the code but it supposed to take only 3 keys:

```
if data["news"] == [] and data["ad"] == [] and data["coupon"] == []:
    print('empty')
```

How to take not only 3 keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dictionary is not empty, only your *values* are.

Test each value, using the [`any` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if not any(data.values()):
    # all values are empty, or there are no keys
```

This is the most efficient method; `any()` returns `True` as soon as it encounters one value that is not empty:

```
>>> data = {'news': [], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
>>> not any(data.values())
True
>>> data["news"].append("No longer empty")
>>> not any(data.values())
False
```

Here, *not empty* means: the value has [boolean truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) that is `True`. It'll also work if your values are other containers (sets, dictionaries, tuples), but also with any other Python object that follows the normal truth value conventions.

There is no need to do anything different if the dictionary is empty (has no keys):

```
>>> not any({})
True
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's not empty, but all of it's values are falsy:

```py
if data and not any(data.values()):
    print(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

side by side comparison to better help understand the any() function and to check of empty values.

```
# sample code
val_1 = {'news': [], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
print(val_1)
print(any(val_1.values()))

val_2 = {'news': [1, 2], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
print(val_2)
print(any(val_2.values()))


# prints out
{'news': [], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
False
{'news': [1, 2], 'ad': [], 'coupon': []}
True
```